Error Consuming a StencilJS Component Library inside NextJS
I have a StencilJS component library I'm self hosting on GitLab. It's a private repo.
I'm able to consume it within regular HTML, however I would like to use the StencilJS Web Components within a NextJS app.  But I'm receiving errors.
Here's the NextJS Error (it cannot find the loader module)
Server Error
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\x\mynextproject\node_modules\@mypackage\shared-components\loader\index.cjs'

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
createEsmNotFoundErr
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1181:15)
finalizeEsmResolution
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1169:15)
resolveExports
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (591:14)
Module._findPath
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (668:31)
Module._resolveFilename
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1130:27)

Here is my import
import { defineCustomElements } from '@mypackage/shared-components/loader';

And here is my use of defineCustomElements
  useEffect(() => {
    defineCustomElements();
  }, []);

I would simply like to use the element like this:
<ReactComponents/>
<my-stencil-component></my-stencil-component>

I tried referencing the cjs.js file, the index.js files at import, but it doesn't work.
I tried using defineCustomElements outside of the react component
I have also tried updating my tsconfig.json to include paths
"paths": {
      "@mypackage/shared-components/loader": ["node_modules/@mypackage/shared-components/loader"]
    },


I ended up changing the stenciljs package.json exports entry for ./loader
from
"./loader": {
      "import": "./loader/index.js",
      "require": "./loader/index.cjs",
      "types": "./loader/index.d.ts"
    }

to
"./loader": {
      "import": "./loader/index.js",
      "require": "./loader/index.cjs.js",
      "types": "./loader/index.d.ts"
    }

NextJs was attempting to read a .cjs file but stencil outputs a .cjs.js file.
I also kept the paths entry in the tsconfig.json file
